# Cross-Platform Job Scheduling with Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I have a java application (jar file) and I want to add some sort of scheduling option in it. This means that the application will offer users the ability to carry out a particular job automatically in intervals as defined by the users themselves. I was thinking of calling the scheduler from the command line (through Java code), such as using the 'AT' command for Windows and Anacron for UNIX-based systems.

My first part of the question is about the 'AT' command in Windows:

I have tried using the 'AT' command from the command line directly however I can't seem to get it to work. The job is listed as a scheduled task, however when the time elapses the task is not executed. (The task that I'm trying to run is a jar file which runs perfectly normal when I run it from the command line without the scheduling.) Would anyone be kind enough to point out anything that I might be doing wrong? The command I am supplying is as follows:

'AT XX:XX java -jar C:....\xyz.jar' ,where XX:XX is the time that I want to run it at.

The second part of the question is about any other different implementations of such functions:

I am open for ideas, so if there is a different way of implementing such a function please do not hesitate to mention it. The implementation has to be cross-platform and if possible, free.

Comment: I see cross-platform in the tags and AT (windows command) in the question... Anything wrong there? I would recommend the Quartz library instead as @Jim said.

Comment: Sorry about that. I removed the cross-platform tag now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really only an answer to the second part of your question, but you might want to take a look at [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

You can also potentially use a framework like Spring that supports Quartz to simplify and understand the usage further [Quartz Scheduling with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.5/reference/scheduling.html).

Comment: Yes, embedding quartz is much nicer and means it's easier to deploy your application - as no external OS related configuration is required.

Comment: Thanks. I came across it however I thought implementation was quite complex. I will look into it again in more detail.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a link to Quartz Scheduling with Spring that you might want to consider to make definitions and scheduling easier in some cases

Comment: Cheers Jim, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need check  "Task Scheduler" service is started and add FULL path to java

Comment: Task Scheduler was running because I had checked it, and also I am giving the full path (absolute) to the jar file.

Comment: you need give full path of java cmd, such as AT XX:XX c:\xxx\bin\java